# Register XML schema using dbms_xmlschema in Oracle

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, xml

The requirement is to register XML schema from XSD files in Oracle 11gR2. I am using the following code:

```
DECLARE

BEGIN
  DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.registerSchema(
    SCHEMAURL => 'http://[...]/spin-catalog-to-bpm.xsd',
    SCHEMADOC => bfilename ('/home/joe','spin-catalog-to-bpm.xsd'),
    CSID => nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'));
END;
/
```

The file `spin-catalog-to-bpm.xsd` is under `/home/joe` but when I try to register it, it gives me this error:

```
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-22285: non-existent directory or file for FILEOPEN operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 805
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XMLSCHEMA", line 131
ORA-06512: at line 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You firstly need to create and Oracle directory.

As a user with the relevant permissions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY HOMEJOE AS '/home/joe';
```

Grant permission to the user that needs to use `DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.registerSchema`:

```
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY HOMEJOE TO YOURUSER;
```

Then register the schema, using the newly created directory:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.registerSchema(
    SCHEMAURL => 'http://[...]/spin-catalog-to-bpm.xsd',
    SCHEMADOC => bfilename ('HOMEJOE','spin-catalog-to-bpm.xsd'),
    CSID => nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'));
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Phil, but i am still wondering that what if i don't have access to create directory on database server. There should be a way that i can register xml schema having the xsd file at a remote location.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for saving an XML Schema in a location were you are able to control it is the XDB Repository:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb16fol.htm#i1042688

You can create files or select their content via XDB functionality that supports FTP/WebDAV or HTTP...